# App to interact with multiple smart contracts

Tags: dapps

I'm trying to find info on retrieving data and calling functions on 2 contracts using the same app. It's for an NFT management app; the user can view their NFT images, data and mint more using the NFTs main contract, but I'd like them to be able to make calls to an second contract with extended functions without loading a separate app altogether.
Is there a way to achieve this without creating an interface smart contract that has all functions to both contracts in it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand your questions.
You want to call two(or more) different functions from two different contracts without having two separate apps?

Obviously, you can have two different contract addresses and abi's and can use them to call different function calls depending upon the contract.

Comment: Ah Ok, it wasn't that obvious (to me atleast). I thought I'd have to amalgamate the abis but have found I can simply extend connect() to reference each contract. Thanks for the nudge